# Latitude and Longitude as per mapview

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Can anyone tell me that when we scroll or move mkmapview then according to movement can get the lat long from mkmapview ?
I want lat long as we move the mapview.

Comment: When we move mkmapview then below delegate method is called and then we get mapView.centerCoordinate; and we get it.

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mMapView.centerCoordinate;
```

will return the center CLLocationCoordinate2D of the map.